# How can I merge individual object values?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following problem:

I want to read out my table names from a SQL database and then make a comparison as to whether it already exists. I know there is the formula IF EXISTS ... but IF doesn't work .. So here's my previous variant:

First i extracted everything before the filename.csv (C:\Users\Frederic\Desktop\Drag&Drop...) and then the ".csv". Do not be surprised why 51;) The filename is so long

```
var filename  = filePath.slice(51);
    var richtigername = filename.replace(".csv","").toString();
    console.log(richtigername)
```

here the result in the console:

for example: fxbewertung

As a second step I let me show the file names:

```
        connection.query('Show tables from datein', function(err, datein) {
        let string = JSON.stringify(datein);
        let json =  JSON.parse(string);
        console.log(json)
```

here the result in the console:

```
[ { Tables_in_datein: 'fxbewertung' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'kontoauszug' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'lsreport' } ]
```

Furthermore, I extracted the values (name of the SQL tables):

```
     for (var k = 0; k < json.length; k++) { 
         var werte = Object.values(json[k])
             console.log(werte)
     };
```

here the result in the console:

```
[ 'fxbewertung' ]
[ 'kontoauszug' ]
[ 'lsreport' ]
```

Now I don't know how i can take the comparison that for example for the file fxbewertung exist a database ('fxbewertung').

My consideration is to somehow browse the individual arrays .. or merge and then browse. At the end should come out true or false

P.S .: it may well be complicated yet but I'm not a real programmer or something;)

Best regards

Frederic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to check if a table exists for that filename.

```
 var tableExists = tables.some(item => item['Tables_in_datein'] === filename);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var tables = [{
    Tables_in_datein: 'fxbewertung'
  },
  {
    Tables_in_datein: 'kontoauszug'
  },
  {
    Tables_in_datein: 'lsreport'
  }
];

var filename = 'fxbewertung';

var tableExists = tables.some(item => item['Tables_in_datein'] === filename);

if (!tableExists) {
  // Table not found for filename.
} else {
  // Table found. Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you finished executing your query and stored the data as following:

```
const queryResult = [ { Tables_in_datein: 'fxbewertung' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'kontoauszug' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'lsreport' } ]
```

You'll then need to `map` this array to extract the values and store them in a single array like so:

```
const values = queryResult.map(e=>e[Object.keys(e)[0]]) // ["fxbewertung", "kontoauszug", "lsreport"]
```

Since you're looking for a true/false result by giving a file name, you'll need to use `indexOf` to achieve that.

```
const valueExists = filename => values.indexOf(filename) !== -1
```

After that execute `valueExists` with the file name you're looking for:

```
valueExists("kontoauszug"); // true
valueExists("potato"); // false
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

An efficient solution could be to use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Where it would return from the moment it finds a truthy value and would not iterate till the end (unless the match exists at the end).

**Demo Code:**

```js
const tablesArr = [
  {
Tables_in_datein: "fxbewertung"
  },
  {
Tables_in_datein: "kontoauszug"
  },
  {
Tables_in_datein: "lsreport"
  }
];

const tabletoFind = "fxbewertung";

const tableFound = tablesArr.find(item => item["Tables_in_datein"] === tabletoFind) ? true: false;

console.log(tableFound);

if(tableFound){
//*yes table found*/
}else{
///*nope table not found*/
}
```